# Z-Index Problems

Tags: html, css, z-index

So I've got a div that I want to appear in front of every other div on the page. Here's all my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Koowalk Game Development - Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="koowalk.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <h4 id="header">KOOWALK</h4>
    <h4 id="headerb">GAMES</h4>

    <p>Hello. We're Koowalk Games. We make games.</p>

    <div id="work">
        <p id="workheader">Games</p>

        <div id="workbar"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        var bar = document.getElementById("workbar");
        var x = 0;

        window.onload = change;

        function change() {
            requestAnimationFrame(color);
        }

        function color() {
            bar.style.background = "hsl(" + x + ", 100%, 50%)";
            if (x < 358) {
                x++;
                requestAnimationFrame(color);
            }

            else {
                x = 0;
                requestAnimationFrame(color);
            }
        }
        </script>

        <div class="workleft">
            <p class="headerleft">Some Game</p>

            <p class="pleft">This will be some kind of description of the game. There will also     be a picture to the left. Cause I know how much you love pictures. I'm in bio. Dransfield is about to yell at me. Except he isn't. Why am I writing this, you might ask? Just think appearences. It's all about the appearences.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="sliding1"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
@font-face {font-family: "Veger"; src: url('Fonts/Veger(light).ttf'); }
@font-face {font-family: "Kloe"; src: url('Fonts/ff4a_kloe_thin-web.ttf'); }

::selection {
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    color: white;
}

::-moz-selection {
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 89%);
    color: white;
}

body {
    background: #5a5a5a;
    font-family: Veger;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
#header {
    font-size: 100px;
    color: #49ffdc;
}

#headerb {
    font-size: 100px;
    margin-top: -145px;
    color: #ffff63;
}

p {
    font-family: Kloe, sans;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-right: 15%;
    margin-top: -40px;
}

#work {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background: #ff4545;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

#workheader {
    font-family: Kloe, sans;
    font-size: 80px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#workbar {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right: 25%;
    height: 3px;
    margin-top: -70px;
    background: hsl(0, 100%, 50%);
}

.workleft {
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-top: -20px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #5a5a5a;
    color: white;
    font-family: Kloe, sans;
    text-align: right;
}

.headerleft {
    margin-right: 5%;
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-top: -5px;
}

.pleft {
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-left: 50%;
    font-size: 15px;

}

#sliding1 { //This is the div that needs to appear in front of everything
    z-index: 2;
    width: 47%;
    height: 10px;
    color: #06168d;
}
```

As you can see, #sliding1 is the div I need to get in front of everything else. I've never used z-index before. The div is showing up, but it's behind everything. How do you use z-index exactly?

EDIT: This is not duplicate. I looked at most of the other questions, and all the answers that were provided didn't work. I now have position: absolute and it is still not working.

Comment: OP accepted a duplicate answer, therefore even they agree it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use `z-index` you have to add `position` to the element.

```
#sliding1 {
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
}
```

> The z-index property in CSS controls the vertical stacking order of
>   elements that overlap. As in, which one appears as if it is physically
>   closer to you. z-index only effects elements that have a position
>   value other than static (the default).

Reference: [css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/)

Comment: Still not working... position is set to relative. I tried just about every other position as well.

Comment: It works just fine. Are you sure you didn't mean to set the background color on that #sliding1 div instead of the color? The color only affects the text. See http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/uvnudvv9/